# Fail to deploy my own nodejs to aws elastic bean stalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a valid node.js app that I want to deploy to AWS EB. It is valid because it is working on my localhost by:

npm start

The zip that I upload looks like this:

[image: folder structure]

My app.js looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var sequelize = require('sequelize');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var responseDTO = require('./dto/httpResponseDTO.js');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    msg = responseDTO.toReseponseDTO(false, err.name, err.errors);
    res.json(msg);
});


module.exports = app;
```

**EDIT**

The package.json looks like:

```
{
    "name" : #projectname#,
    "version" : "0.1.1",
    "private" : true,
    "scripts" : {
            "start" : "node ./bin/www"
    },
    "dependencies" : {
...
    }
}
```

And the file that the script tries to run (./bin/www) looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('mee:server');
var http = require('http');
var models = require('../models');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8081');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
    }
    if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
    }
    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

It looks like this is causing problem to EB, which says:

```
Impaired services on all instances.
```

The error log says:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
npm ERR! Linux 3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! path /var/app/current/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open '/var/app/current/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Linux 3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! path /var/app/current/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
```

It looks like the package.json isn't found? but from the folder structure it is there...

Please let me know what went wrong, it has been bothering me for a long time!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted I cannot see the part when you actually start the server but from the logs I see that it starts in port 8081 which it is actually strange to me, I guess in EBS it must have a dynamic PORT

When you select the port you should use `process.env.PORT || 8081` this will get the port set by EBS or use 8081 (in local for example).

Amazon has a good guide which should explain you how to deploy there a node app: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

Comment: hmm, I don't know where do we usually put the starting the server line in the code - on local I manually type in npm start; but I thought EB's nodejs runtime should does that?

Comment: Yes but inside the code you start the webserver i guess and you set a port to it. If not how would you know to connect to port 8081? In that line you have to add the env variable that i said above

Comment: I just updated the question to include the file that starts the server, as well as the line that you suggested. However I still see the same problem.. Please advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out for some reason, when I remote into the linux ec2 instance used by the EB, and try node --version or sudo node --version, it says command not found. I have to manually install node and npm and manually start the server. It's weird that I have to do this though..

Comment: You actually don't need to install node or npm manually at all, and is actually not advised. ElasticBeanstalk does not set environment variables for the node or npm processes so you have to instead perform a find to figure out where those processes are saved. These should be located in a directory like so: `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/`.